# Share video with react-native-fbsdk

Tags: facebook, react-native, share, react-native-fbsdk

I'm trying to share a video from my React Native app, that I record with react-native-camera just before.
This video path is something like `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/XXX.mov` on iOS.

I did the same thing with photos and it's working well, but whenever I'm trying with videos:

```
let shareContent = {
    contentType: 'video',
    video: {
      localUrl: encodeURI(content.uri),
    },
  };

ShareApi.canShare(shareContent).then(
  function(canShare) {
    console.warn("canShare: " + canShare);
    if (canShare) {
      return ShareDialog.show(shareContent);
    }
  }
).then(
  function(result) {
    console.warn(result);
  },
  function(error) {
    console.warn(error);
  }
);
```

I get a "Invalid value for videoURL" response.
I can share local photos the same way so I guess it's possible to perform the same action with videos, but I can't figure it out.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Stop guessing, and _verify_ instead, by checking the documentation …?

Comment: @CBroe https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/tree/master/js/models I checked this and everything's set

Answer (score -1):

localUrl needs to be an asset. Example:

localUrl: 'assets-library://asset/asset.mp4?id=225640F8-597C-4E71-A1E9-490C7737B0E4&ext=mp4'

If you use ImagePicker to select the video you can get the asset using:

ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
...
this.setState({localVideoUri: response.origURL})